# MongoDB query not working with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have problem within my meteor.js app, with mongo to be more precise. When I try to make this update query in my Meteor.JS application it is not working, it's throwing this error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'deleteNotifications' MongoError: '$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$mod: {<field>: ...}}
```

He is complaining that I'm not using $set mongo mod, but here's the thing, I don't want to use it, you can see my query below (I'm using coffeescript).

```
Messages.update
  _id:
    $in: messagesIds
,
  $push:
    readByReceivers: Meteor.userId()
,
  multi: true
```

All needed values are present, the most interesting thing is that if I use $set instead of $push then query is processed.

When I try the same query inside mongo  for meteor app then it's working perfectly:

```
db.messages.update({_id: {$in: ["x6PpcE829GsWarjB5"]}},{$push: {readByReceivers: "nx7XkXsmeMh6pz5n3"}},{multiple: true})
```

Why is meteor forcing me to use $set ?

Comment: Can you use a variable that holds the value from the function `Meteor.userId()` instead?

Comment: All needed values are present, holding Meteor.userId() inside variable and then using that variable doesn't change anything, error stays the same.

Comment: Working example: `Item.update { _id: itemId }, $push: users: user._id` from my project

Comment: A silly question: are you sure that readByReceivers is an array in the db? Presumably if it's not an array, mongo would throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

The option `multi: true` is not allowed on the client. Use a Meteor Method instead (it is allowed on the server).